# Does breeding two of the same dragon always yield an egg of that same type?

Tags: dragonvale

In Dragonvale I noticed breeding two Pang Long dragons yields another Pan Long dragon, and advice for breeding Holiday dragons on the Dragonvale wiki suggests you can only get expired time-limited dragons by breeding two of the same dragon.

Does breeding two of the same dragon always give another one of the same dragon, or can they mix and create a hybrid dragon like other dragons?

Answer (score 1):

Generally they will breed a child of the same exact type, at least 95% of the time in my experience. However they can breed a hybrid of their elements.

When breeding two Chrome dragons (air/metal) repeatedly I found that once I got a Rust dragon (Metal+water)! This is because, apparently, on rare occasion an Air dragon breeds as a fire or water dragon instead of an air dragon.

Comment: I think this answer may be out of date. I think same pairs now always result in the same child (no hybrid splits). Also, I believe gem dragons are an exception (individuals are "sterile").

Answer (score 0):

I am almost positive they can mix and create a hybrid dragon. I am trying to remember if it happened to me, but I can't seem to recall... It is most likely that it creates the same type of dragon, but I believe it is possible to have a random combination of the elements within the dragon, as long as it is not one of the basic dragons of course.

Comment: I've been meaning to test this by breeding my Pang Long dragons a bunch (4 elements, lots of possible non-Pang Long kids) but I haven't gotten to do it yet

Comment: That's a good idea. Unfortunately I only have 1 panlong so I will have to test it with something else. I tend to get rid of my doubles, only double I had currently is moss. I'll start breeding those and tell you my findings. So far after 2 tries they have both been another moss. Panlong is probably smarter so I may try to make another and test them together. This is an interesting question...

Comment: Doubles are what the hibernation cave is for!

Answer (score 0):

I have been breeding two iron dragons for cash for about a month solid. It has always been another iron. Then today 10-11-13 two iron dragons gave me a bronze dragon. I would say they do have a chance to give you something else.