# How does the Dragonvale expired concept work?

Tags: dragonvale

Can EVERY SINGLE dragon be breed? Even if some of them are ''expired''?

For instance the Rose Dragon is expired. But can I still manage to breed it with the right combination? Does the ''expired'' term only apply to the amount of time you have to physically buy it in the market before you have no choice but to breed it? Or before it is no longer available to breed anymore in the game at all? Such that even if you breed An Air and Flower dragon there is no chance of getting it because it is ''expired''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a dragon is expired, there is no chance to obtain that dragon via the breeding pairs that would normally produce that dragon.  Part of the fun (and part of the monetization scheme) is having limited time to obtain the limited dragons.  If you've missed obtaining them, all is not lost, though:

1. Many of the limited time dragons are actually on a schedule and opportunities to breed them reappear at regular intervals.  As an example, the Reindeer dragon is available to be bred every Christmas season.
2. If you have two of the same limited dragon, breeding them may produce that dragon, even if that dragon is currently unavailable to be bred in any other manner.  Note that when I played Dragonvale, breeding two of the same dragon always produced that dragon.  From what I have read recently, that has changed and you now just have a chance to produce the type of dragon that matches the breeding pair.

Finally, you may wish to review a few of our other Dragonvale questions, as they pertain to limited dragons:

- [Is there a list of the “current” limited dragons anywhere?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106889/is-there-a-list-of-the-current-limited-dragons-anywhere)
- [Does breeding two of the same dragon always yield an egg of that same type?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52683/does-breeding-two-of-the-same-dragon-always-yield-an-egg-of-that-same-type)
- [Do I need to keep more than one of each dragon type?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94814/do-i-need-to-keep-more-than-one-of-each-dragon-type)

Comment: Don't forget, that around Christmas, everything is available. Dragonvale often has a Christmas in July event, during which time, any dragon can be breed, even the very limited never to get a breeding season dragons like the Light Rift dragon and the Dark Rift dragon.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Two of the same dragon will still breed the retired dragon. It is sometimes also possible to obtain a retired dragon with only one breeding aswell. Combinations of two different dragons may work sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

The nightmare dragon has been expired since roughly January 2015 and today June 9th 2015 the combo daydream dragon and nightmare dragon in the upgraded breeding cave resulted in a Nightmare dragon.  Therefore it is possible to breed a non-available dragon with only one parent dragon of that type after that particular dragon has expired.  Thought this example might help.